# Rounding entries in a Pandas DafaFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Using :

```
newdf3.pivot_table(rows=['Quradate'],aggfunc=np.mean)
```

which yields:

```
           Alabama_exp  Credit_exp  Inventory_exp   National_exp    Price_exp   Sales_exp
Quradate                        
2010-01-15   0.568003    0.404481    0.488601    0.483097    0.431211    0.570755
2010-04-15   0.543620    0.385417    0.455078    0.468750    0.408203    0.564453
```

I'd like to get the decimal numbers rounded to two digit and multiplied by 100 eg .568003 should be 57 been fiddling with it for a while to no avail; tried this

```
newdf3.pivot_table(rows=['Quradate'],aggfunc=np.mean).apply(round(2)) #and got:
TypeError: ("'float' object is not callable", u'occurred at index Alabama_exp')
```

Tried a number of other approaches to no avail most complain about the item not being a float... I see that the Pandas series object has a round method but DF does not I tried using df.apply but it complained about the float issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use `numpy.round`, e.g.:

```
100 * np.round(newdf3.pivot_table(rows=['Quradate'], aggfunc=np.mean), 2)
```

As long as round is appropriate for all column types, this works on a `DataFrame`.

With some data:

```
In [9]: dfrm
Out[9]:
          A         B         C
0 -1.312700  0.760710  1.044006
1 -0.792521 -0.076913  0.087334
2 -0.557738  0.982031  1.365357
3  1.013947  0.345896 -0.356652
4  1.278278 -0.195477  0.550492
5  0.116599 -0.670163 -1.290245
6 -1.808143 -0.818014  0.713614
7  0.233726  0.634349  0.561103
8  2.344671 -2.331232 -0.759296
9 -1.658047  1.756503 -0.996620

In [10]: 100*np.round(dfrm, 2)
Out[10]:
     A    B    C
0 -131   76  104
1  -79   -8    9
2  -56   98  137
3  101   35  -36
4  128  -20   55
5   12  -67 -129
6 -181  -82   71
7   23   63   56
8  234 -233  -76
9 -166  176 -100
```

Comment: Nice. I get 41 ms on ``np.round`` to 82 ms on Cloud's solution.

Comment: Each solution has it's merits but in the end this is most straightforward and quick. Thank you

Comment: I agree, each of the solutions mentions valuable pieces of info and the other two offer a lot more info if you need to generalize to functions that aren't readily applied directly to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 9):

Since Pandas 0.17, DataFrames have a ['round'](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) method:

```
df =newdf3.pivot_table(rows=['Quradate'],aggfunc=np.mean)
df.round()
```

which even allows you to have different precision for each column

```
df.round({'Alabama_exp':2, 'Credit_exp':3})
```

Answer (score 6):

For a modestly sized `DataFrame`, `applymap` will be horrendously slow, since it is applying a Python function element by element in Python (i.e., there's no Cython speeding this up). It's faster to use `apply` with `functools.partial`:

```
In [22]: from functools import partial

In [23]: df = DataFrame(randn(100000, 20))

In [24]: f = partial(Series.round, decimals=2)

In [25]: timeit df.applymap(lambda x: round(x, 2))
1 loops, best of 3: 2.52 s per loop

In [26]: timeit df.apply(f)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.4 ms per loop
```

You could even make a function that returns a partial function that you can apply:

```
In [27]: def column_round(decimals):
   ....:     return partial(Series.round, decimals=decimals)
   ....:

In [28]: df.apply(column_round(2))
```

As @EMS suggests, you can use `np.round` as well, since `DataFrame` implements the `__array__` attribute and automatically wraps many of `numpy`'s ufuncs. It's also about twice as fast with the frame shown above:

```
In [47]: timeit np.round(df, 2)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.4 ms per loop
```

If you have non-numeric columns you can do this:

```
In [12]: df = DataFrame(randn(100000, 20))

In [13]: df['a'] = tm.choice(['a', 'b'], size=len(df))

In [14]: dfnum = df._get_numeric_data()

In [15]: np.round(dfnum)
```

to avoid the cryptic error thrown by `numpy` when you try to round a column of strings.

Comment: Why not use `numpy.round` and pass the `DataFrame` as an argument? `100 * np.round(df, 2)` seems to solve the problem for me. If some columns have type inappropriate for `round`, just exclude them before passing to the `round` function. This should avoid overhead from `apply`-like things.

Comment: this is a great explanation, but I think the np round solution is simple and quick, thank you for all the help, this answer helps a lot for a full understanding.

Answer (score 3):

**I'm leaving this here for the explanation of why the OP's approach threw an error, but subsequent solutions are better.**

The best solution is to simply use Series' `round` method:

```
In [11]: s
Out[11]: 
0    0.026574
1    0.304801
2    0.057819
dtype: float64

In [12]: 100*s.round(2)
Out[12]:  
0     3
1    30
2     6
dtype: float64
```

You might tack `.astype('int')` on there as well, depending on what you want to do next.

To understand why your approach didn't work, remember that the function `round` needs two arguments, the number of decimal places *and the data to be rounded*. In general, to apply functions that take two arguments, you can "curry" the function like so:

```
In [13]: s.apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
Out[13]: 
0    1.03
1    1.30
2   -1.06
dtype: float64
```

*As DSM points out on the comments, for this case one actually needs the currying approach -because there is no `round` method for DataFrames. `df.applymap(...)` is the way to go.*

Comment: I'm not sure this quite tells the whole story.  The result of `pivot_table` will be a `DataFrame`, and you can't `.apply(lambda x: round(x,2))` to a `DataFrame` because the `x`s will be `Series`.  You could use `applymap`, I think.

Comment: I see that, you are correct, but still can't quite get the "right" syntax to use on the Dataframe and I need a Dataframe at the end as well.

Comment: That did it newdf3.pivot_table(rows=['Quradate'],aggfunc=np.mean).applymap(lambda x: round(x,2))

Comment: And to finish it off newdf3.pivot_table(rows=['Quradate'],aggfunc=np.mean).applymap(lambda x: round(x,2)*100) if DSM could provide the answer in answer form I'll mark it..

Comment: Just use `numpy.round`, e.g. `import numpy as np; 100*np.round(s, 2);` As long as `round` is appropriate for all column types, this works on a DataFrame.