# The right way to round pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I want round `pandas.DataFrame`.

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([1.4,2.5,3.8,4.4,5.6],[6.2,7.6,8.8,9.1,0])
print(round(data))
```

But when i run this code, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\*****\******\****.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(round(data))
TypeError: type DataFrame doesn't define __round__ method
```

**What is the right way to round `pandas.DataFrame` ?**

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19100540/564538

Answer (score 14, accepted):

first, you may want to change the definition of your data frame, something like:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1.4,2.5,3.8,4.4,5.6],[6.2,7.6,8.8,9.1,0]]).T
```

which results this:

```
     0    1
0  1.4  6.2
1  2.5  7.6
2  3.8  8.8
3  4.4  9.1
4  5.6  0.0
```

or:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.4,2.5,3.8,4.4,5.6],'B':[6.2,7.6,8.8,9.1,0]})
```

so that you get two columns, otherwise the other list is picked up as index; then:

```
data.apply(pd.Series.round)
```

or

```
import numpy as np
data.apply(np.round)
```

Comment: this rounds only first column

Comment: the way you are making the dataframe, the other column is index, pandas apply the functions to columns not the index

Comment: what about series, how can i round them?

Comment: series have method `round`, so just `ts.round`

Comment: Here is the best solution: `np.round(data, decimals=0)`

Answer (score 6):

Since pandas 0.17.0 you can use

```
DataFrame.round(decimals=0, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to round your data to 2 decimals do:

```
data.round(2)
```

more info here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html

Answer (score 0):

For those that come here but did not actually want to round the values, just when diplaying, use printoption as I explained in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72826990/11671779)

```py
pd.set_option('display.precision', 3)

# or

from IPython.display import display

with pd.option_context('display.precision', 3):
    display(pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[1,2,3],
                               'y':[4,5,6]}))
```