# iPython Notebook not printing Dataframe as table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to print a df in ipython notebook but it doesn't print it as a table.

```
data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012],
        'team': ['Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Packers', 'Packers', 'Lions', 'Lions', 'Lions'],
        'wins': [11, 8, 10, 15, 11, 6, 10, 4],
        'losses': [5, 8, 6, 1, 5, 10, 6, 12]}
football = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'team', 'wins', 'losses'])

print football
```

Output

```
   year     team  wins  losses
0  2010    Bears    11       5
1  2011    Bears     8       8
2  2012    Bears    10       6
3  2011  Packers    15       1
4  2012  Packers    11       5
5  2010    Lions     6      10
6  2011    Lions    10       6
7  2012    Lions     4      12
```

I tried "display" as suggested [Show DataFrame as table in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/print-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook):

```
from IPython.display import display
#.....
print display(football)
```

Also tried:

```
pandas.core.format.set_printoptions(notebook_repr_html=True)
```

but got error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_printoptions'
```

How can I print my df as a table with nice vertical and horizontal lines?

Comment: Does it work if you do this: `pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', True)`

Comment: Also what version pandas are you using? the options were moved around version 0.13 I think to `set_option`

Comment: @EdChum - yep, used that but still nothing, how can I find the version I'm using?

Comment: `pd.version.version` will output the version, I get a HTML table fine in my version of pandas and ipython, I'm using `0.15.2` and `2.3.0` pandas and ipython respectively

Comment: does `football.to_html()` work?

Comment: df.to_html() didnt work, it literally returned html code.

Comment: Got it to work by simplying saying "football" in a new cell with pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', True)

Comment: print will output a text representation which is not what you want

Comment: Had no idea! Complete newb to Ipython Notebook but loving it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`set_printoptions` has been replaced by `set_options` in the more recent versions of *pandas*, try to use:

```
pandas.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', True)
```

Also do not use `print`, simply state `football` or `display(football)` in the last line of a notebook cell.

Comment: Thanks, I had to simply state "football" in a new cell, a bit odd? but it works.

Comment: `notebook_repr_html` defaults to `True` so you shouldn't need to set it.

Comment: Python will always try to represent the last thing that was output with a default display, that's why `football` by itself or at the end of a cell works.