# HTML not rendering properly with Canopy 1.7.1.3323 / IPython 4.1.2

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, canopy

I've just upgraded to Canopy 1.7.1; I think this problem stems from the change in IPython version from 2.4.1 to 4.1.2.

The issue I have is that calling a DataFrame object in Python seems to use the `__print__` method, i.e. there's no difference between  typing `print df` and `df` into the interpreter, and unfortunately this gives me an all-text output rather than the nice tables I normally get.

So I get something that looks exactly like this when I call `df` rather than a table:

```
           date  flag
1      20151102     0
98663  20151101     1
```

This happened immediately after the upgrade, and I also tried updating all my packages. I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/print-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801379/ipython-notebook-not-printing-dataframe-as-table?lq=1), but none of the solutions there work for me. (`'display.notebook_repr_html'` is already `True`)

EDIT: The issue seems to do with rendering HTML; typing in

```python
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'))
```

returns

```python
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

Comment: I think you are correct that this relates to the change in IPython (I am seeing the same behavior with conda, so I don't think it is a Canopy-specific issue). The referenced suggestions work for Jupyter notebooks, but not at the IPython prompt. Possibly a bug in IPython? One thing you can try is using `view(df)` from Enthought's new catalyst package (`from catalyst.api import view`). This will open a dataframe viewer which is part of the new Data Import Tool (available to subscribers). The dataframe viewer itself is available to all users.

Comment: Thank you, the DataFrame viewer works and is definitely useful, though I would still like to see the table being rendered properly in the interpreter output (but it does seem more like it's an issue with IPython beyond my control)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has purposely been disabled. I have requested a way to have it re-enabled but but unsupported.

Please see the request. https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/165