# Canopy IPython not displaying HTML inline

Tags: python, ipython

I've searched across stackoverflow and a number of other sites and Im not quite finding the answer to my problem.  In short, when I run Python from either the interactive command line or from a source file in Canopy, and that code involves attempting to display a panda dataframe or even manual markup as html, it does not work.  I simply get the following output:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

I have checked preferences and have looked for other possible sources of error.  I have tried different combinations of imports and diplay methods as below.  They all return the same thing above, never the actual HTML.

```
#from IPython.display import HTML
#from IPython.core.display import display
#display_html(av.head(10).to_html())

from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML('<h1>Hello World</h1>'))
```

Note that av is just a dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated.  I feel like there is a ridiculously simple fix I am missing.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the raw markup to display, or how to actually render it?  You can only render HTML in a browser, so there's no way a plaintext environment like a regular Python console is going to actually show you the rendered HTML.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was of the understanding that IPython could render HTML inline on the console.  Regardless though, it wouldn't even spit out the raw HTML anywhere that I could find.

Comment: It looks like you can get the raw HTML from the `.data` attribute of the HTML object, e.g., `HTML('<h1>Hello World</h1>').data`.  For a DataFrame, just using `to_html()` by itself (without using any of the IPython display stuff) will give you the HTML representation.

Comment: Thanks!  At the very least the .data attribute should be useful.  I believe I already tried to_html() with no luck though.

Comment: Are you saying `print(av.head().to_html())` doesn't show you HTML source?

Comment: It actually worked this time!  Spat out the raw HTML to the console.  I'm new to Python but I assume I could also just write it to a file and voila I'd be good to go.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It might be this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041696/html-not-rendering-properly-with-canopy-1-7-1-3323-ipython-4-1-2