# python - Dataframe objects in Jupyter notebook do not output in a stylized grid as they should

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Whenever I print a pandas dataframe in Jupyter Notebook, I get an basic unformatted row-by-column list:

Current dataframe output in Jupyter:

[image]

However, I understood that the default behavior is to output dataframes in a more stylized object with gridlines:

Desired dataframe styling in Jupyter:

[image]

What do I need to do so that dataframes are printed as they are stylistically in the second example?

Comment: Try without using the `print` function.

Comment: This question is answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/print-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/print-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook). In short, use the *display* method from IPython.display method.