# Databricks display() function equivalent or alternative to Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I'm in the process of migrating current DataBricks Spark notebooks to Jupyter notebooks, DataBricks provides convenient and beautiful display(data_frame) function to be able to visualize Spark dataframes and RDDs ,but there's no direct equivalent for Jupyter(im not sure but i think its a DataBricks specific function), i tried :

```
dataframe.show()
```

But it's a text version of it ,when you have many columns it breaks , so i'm trying to find an alternative to display() that can render Spark dataframes better than show() functions. Is there any equivalent or alternative to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/show-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: Thanks, so `.show()` is pretty much a worse version of `display()` in databricks (where available)

Comment: If you're using Scala Almond kernel in Jupyter, you can use this solution https://github.com/almond-sh/almond/issues/180 (add `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` to the top)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use Jupyter, instead of using df.show() use myDF.limit(10).toPandas().head().  And, as sometimes, we are working multiple columns it truncates the view.
So just set your Pandas view column config to the max.

```
# Alternative to Databricks display function.
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_columns', None)
```

`myDF.limit(10).toPandas().head()`[image]

Comment: As of Version 1.4 of pandas, you have to use the key "display.max_columns". Reference https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option

Answer (score 4):

First Recommendation: When you use Jupyter, don't use `df.show()` instead use `df.limit(10).toPandas().head()` which results perfect display even better Databricks `display()`

Second Recommendation:
Zeppelin Notebook. Just use `z.show(df.limit(10))`

Additionally in Zeppelin;

1. You register your dataframe as SQL Table `df.createOrReplaceTempView('tableName')`
2. Insert new paragraph beginning `%sql` then query your table with amazing display.

Answer (score 3):

You can set config `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled', True)`.
This will allow to display native pyspark DataFrame without explicitly using df.show() and there is also no need to transfer DataFrame to Pandas either, all you need to is just `df`.

Comment: I know it has been almost a year since you posted this, and I know it didn't became the top answer, but I just wanted to come by and say you are an absolute angel sent from the heavens and a life saver. This is what I spent the whole afternoon looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In recent IPython, you can just use `display(df)` if df is a panda dataframe, it will just work. On older version you might need to do a `from IPython.display import display`. It will also automatically display if the result of the last expression of a cell is a data_frame. For example [this notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/koldunovn/nk_public_notebooks/blob/master/Apache_log.ipynb).  Of course the representation will depends on the library you use to make your dataframe. If you are using PySpark and it does not defined a nice representation by default, then you'll need to teach IPython how to display the Spark DataFrame. For example [here](https://github.com/ipython/disp) is a project that teach IPython how to display Spark Contexts, and Spark Sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Without converting to pandas dataframe. Use this... This will render dataframe in proper grids.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
display(HTML("<style>pre { white-space: pre !important; }</style>"))

df.show()
```

Answer (score -3):

Try Apache Zeppelin (https://zeppelin.apache.org/).  There's some nice standard visualizations of dataframes, specifically if you use the `sql` interpreter.  There's also support for other useful interpreters as well.