# Issue printing PySpark dataframe as formatted table in Jupyter

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have an PySpark dataframe (df) that I'd like to print as a nicely formatted table in my Jupyter notebook.

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/show-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook), I thought the following code would work:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

pandas_df = df.toPandas()

display(HTML(pandas_df.to_html()))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I get the following error:

```
ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <__main__.UnicodeDecodingStringIO object at 0x7f75c7a8e750>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def printDF(inputDF):
    newDF = inputDF.toPandas()
    from IPython.display import display, HTML
    return HTML(newDF.to_html())
```

You can also move the import statement so that it is imported globally, instead of importing it each time the function is called. Hope this helps.