# multiple matplotlib subplots: interleave pandas dataframe HTML with each subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with multiple rows (1 per trade I want to inspect)

```
trades = pandas.read_csv(...)
```

I want to plot each trade on a matplotlib subplot. I create a `pyplot.figure` using `len(trades)` to create sufficient height

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(40,15 * len(trades)))
```

I then iterate over each trade and generate a plot

```
for i,r in enumerate(trades.iterrows()):
    _, trade = r

    start = trade.open_time  - datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
    end   = trade.close_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30) 

    b = bids[start:end]
    a = asks[start:end]

    ax = fig.add_subplot(len(trades),1,i+1)

    # plot bid/ask
    ax.plot_date(b.index, b, fmt='-',  label='bid')
    ax.plot_date(a.index, a, fmt='-',  label='ask')

    # plot entry/exit markers
    ax.plot(trade.open_time,  trade.open_price,  marker='o', color='b')
    ax.plot(trade.close_time, trade.close_price, marker='o', color='r')

    ax.set_title("Trade {}".format(i+1, fontsize=10)
    ax.set_xlabel("Date")
    ax.set_ylabel("Price")

    ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize='large')

pyplot.show()

# free resources
pyplot.close(fig.number)
```

This works great.

Now, however, I want to display the rendered HTML of the dataframe for the trade in question.

Since I am doing this in a jupyter notebook, from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665452/955273) I was able to find the following snippet which will display my dataframe in html:

```
t = pandas.DataFrame(trades.iloc[i]).T
IPython.display.display(IPython.display.HTML(t.to_html())
```

I insert this snippet into my loop.

The problem is that each trade's rendered HTML dataframe is printed one-after-the-other, and then after all of the dataframes have been printed, the plots are printed.

```
+-----------+
| dataframe |
+-----------+
+-----------+
| dataframe |
+-----------+
+-----------+
| dataframe |
+-----------+
+------+
|      |
| plot |
|      |
+------+
+------+
|      |
| plot |
|      |
+------+
+------+
|      |
| plot |
|      |
+------+
```

Given I have created a single large `pyplot.figure`, and I call `pyplot.show()` **after** the loop, this makes sense - inside the loop I output the dataframe HTML, and after the loop I display the plot.

**Question:**

How can I interleave the notebook HTML and each subplot?

```
+-----------+
| dataframe |
+-----------+
+------+
|      |
| plot |
|      |
+------+
+-----------+
| dataframe |
+-----------+
+------+
|      |
| plot |
|      |
+------+
+-----------+
| dataframe |
+-----------+
+------+
|      |
| plot |
|      |
+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to create three separate figures and call `plt.show()` within the loop. Something like this (side note, I don't *think* one needs `pyplot.close` using the Jupyter notebook frontend):

```
trades = pandas.read_csv(...)

for i, r in enumerate(trades.iterrows()):
    _, trade = r

    start = trade.open_time  - datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
    end   = trade.close_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30) 

    b = bids[start:end]
    a = asks[start:end]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40, 15))

    # plot bid/ask
    ax.plot_date(b.index, b, fmt='-',  label='bid')
    ax.plot_date(a.index, a, fmt='-',  label='ask')

    # plot entry/exit markers
    ax.plot(trade.open_time,  trade.open_price,  marker='o', color='b')
    ax.plot(trade.close_time, trade.close_price, marker='o', color='r')

    ax.set_title("Trade {}".format(i+1, fontsize=10))
    ax.set_xlabel("Date")
    ax.set_ylabel("Price")

    ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize='large')

    t = pandas.DataFrame(trades.iloc[i]).T
    IPython.display.display(IPython.display.HTML(t.to_html())

    pyplot.show()
```

Comment: damn, it's so obvious! Thank you!