# how to pass a dataframe into string and call function from it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm passing a function who needs a dataframe to execute it, inside a variable string, and using the eval metric i'm trying to execute the function. But the code isn't working because the dataframe becames a string and it fails to understend it.

What i'm doing is:

```
def function(dataframe, number1, number2):
    print(dataframe) #I need this print(dataframe) to print the dtaframe in the correct dataframe format
    print(number1+number2)

dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()
number1 = 1
number2 = 1
a = f'function{dataframe, number1, number2}'
eval(a)
```

But this do'nt work

Comment: `a = f'{function(dataframe, number1, number2)}'`?

Comment: this calls the function automatic, i need to call it just when i use eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call the function and it will work:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas

def function(dataframe, number1, number2):
    display(HTML(dataframe.to_html()))
    print(number1+number2)

dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()
number1 = 1
number2 = 1
a = f'function(dataframe, number1, number2)'
eval(a)
```

If you want to display the datafram in good formatting I suggest reading here: [Show DataFrame as table in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/show-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: i need to use eval, because i need to put many functions in a list and without it, when i declare the list, it calls the function without me wanting it

Comment: Just edited, see if that's what you want @yyz_vanvlet