# Dispaly DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook along with other attributes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

If I just construct a pandas DataFrame in a Jupyter notebook, then the output looks nice:

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})
frame
```

[image]

However, if I make my own class whose `repr` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, then that formatting is lost:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, frame, bar):
        self.frame = frame
        self.bar = bar
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.frame)
```

[image]

How can I define the `repr` of my class `Foo`, such that when I display it in a Jupyter Notebook, it'll look just like it would if it was a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: did you see this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/show-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: yes but I can't just return `HTML(df2.to_html())` from `__repr__`, as `__repr__` needs to return a string

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `repr_html()` method that incorporates what @Atanas Atanasov was suggesting.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, frame, bar):
        self.frame = frame
        self.bar = bar
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.frame)

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return frame.to_html()
```

Below first shows what the OP report and then shows the addition of `repr_html()` in the bottom `Foo` class definition ([4] and [5]) fixes it:

[image]

It's like what Pandas uses for `_repr_html_` in it's [style.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d72e244db5c77833caeebe5f8b38ffea867b1a95/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L379) where it says at the top it is the "Module for applying conditional formatting to DataFrames and Series".

---

#### The Details

The key resource you seek for guidance in making your class integrate well with Jupyter is covered under items like `_repr_html_l` and/or `_repr_mimebundle_` in the ['Integrating your objects with IPython' section in the documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#integrating-your-objects-with-ipython).

I dug around in the Pandas code and it looked like it would be [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d72e244db5c77833caeebe5f8b38ffea867b1a95/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L379) where the `*repr_html*() is defined for Pandas rendering if dataframes. [At the top there](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d72e244db5c77833caeebe5f8b38ffea867b1a95/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L2) it says 'Module for applying conditional formatting to DataFrames and Series.'

See example of use of `_repr_mimebundle_` [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-write-a-class-which-naturally-produce-a-latex-output-in-jupyter-notebook/17437/3?u=fomightez) to make a custom class display latex in a Jupyter notebook rendering.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77908952/8508004) uses the related `_repr_html_()` to make a custom class to control how an SVG object is rendered in the running `.ipynb` file so it remains interactive from scripted details embedded in its encoding file.