# How can I display an interactive SVG image that utilizes javascript in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: javascript, python, svg, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an SVG image with embedded javascript that makes the image change based on `onclick` events:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100">
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[
      function click() {
        var el = document.getElementById("box");
        el.setAttribute("style", "fill: red");
      }
    ]]>
  </script>
  <rect style="fill: white" height="100" x="0" y="0" width="100" onclick="click()" id="box" />
</svg>
```

I would like to display this SVG image in a Jupyter notebook and maintain the interactive functionality.

I tried using

```
from IPython.display import SVG, display
display(SVG('interactive.svg'))
```

And while this displays the svg file, the image does not change from white to red when clicked on.

Comment: Did this code used to work and now it doesn't? Not following what the issue is because you don't mention where the code came from or versions of Jupyter you are using or why you expect it to change to red when clicked on now? If it worked before, you want to look into NbClassic. Otherwise update to use modern approaches in modern Jupyter, which are Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook 7+. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/call-javascript-from-a-button-click-event/10675/4?u=fomightez) for some ideas along that line of tackling this. (Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab tech.)

Comment: This is a new project. If I open the SVG image directly in a new web browser (Chrome) tab, then it is interactive. I am on jupyterlab 3.6.6 and notebook  6.5.2.

Comment: Also tried on jupyterlab  4.0.11 and notebook  7.0.7 - no change in behavior.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to tell you that the newer tech has more strict requirements in general than the older tech. So if you were adapting something from old code then it wouldn't be expected to work in Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook 7+.

Comment: "If I open the SVG image directly in a new web browser (Chrome) tab, then it is interactive." Did you try putting the SVG in an a magic %%HTML cell like you had in your HTML page you open in your browser?

Comment: %%HTML with <img .../> displays the image but it is not interactive.

Comment: Hmmm.. Okay. I found that [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13376#issuecomment-1517759375) works in Jupyter Notebook 7+ (specifically 7.04) and JupyterLab Version 4.0.6 (nothing special about those versions; they are just what I had access to quickly) and so I'm sure what you want is possible; however, I'm hitting my limit of javascripting abilities for now. Note the trick was to make sure to reload the page after running `%load_ext ipyreact`. Not just restarting the kernel, I needed to reload the Jupyter page entirely and then run the react javascript. From that same ...

Comment: <cotninued> thread, did you already try https://github.com/jorgehpo/notebookJS ? (The bi-directional example didn't seem to work for me on first attempt.) By the way, when you say display it in a Jupyter Notebook did you mean with a Python-based kernel? There's Deno if that isn't what you mean. That would look like the better way if you need javascript only, see [Bringing Modern JavaScript to the Jupyter Notebook - The Deno kernel is the freshest runtime for Jupyter](https://blog.jupyter.org/bringing-modern-javascript-to-the-jupyter-notebook-fc998095081e) .

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10464#issuecomment-1532270031

```
from pathlib import Path
from IPython.display import display

class InteractiveSVG:
    def __init__(self, file_name: Path):
        with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as svg_fh:
            self.svg_content = svg_fh.read()
            
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return self.svg_content

display(InteractiveSVG('interactive.svg'))
```