# Jupyter renders classes differently on the console

Tags: python, jupyter

For my own classes, I implement the **repr** to control how the value of an object is rendered in the console (and debugger).

```
>>> class A: 
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return 'foo'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a 
foo
>>> repr(a)
'foo'
>>> print(repr(a))
foo
```

So, apparently, printing the output of repr from an object is equivalent as just letting the console capture the value of the object.
This is true for types as well:

```
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>> print(repr(list))
<class 'list'>
```

But not in Jupyter (Console or notebook)
In a Jupyter console it would print the name of the type only. However, objects will still follow the same rule to print the return value of **repr**.
Here is the i/o from an IPython console

```
In [1]: list
Out[1]: list

In [2]: print(repr(list))
<class 'list'>
```

The question is: What logic is Jupyter following here? Is it simply testing, if the value is a type, and then do a

```
if isinstance(value, type):
  print(value.__name__)
else:
  print(repr(value))
```

Or is there some logic, which one could override?

Comment: Could you please provide the code and the output from Jupyter?

Comment: I think what Yevhen Kuzmovych proposes is spot on. Some examples would help give you actual help. However, I'm thinking what I said under 'The Details' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75152056/8508004) would help you look into this more yourself, first, as it comes from IPython primarily and not Jupyter entirely.

Comment: I added the ouput from IPython. But really, what is spot on is the content behind the link you were posting. I didn't know _repr_html_ exists and how could one conclude from a simple typename, that it is supposed to be html? I propose you make it an answer.