# How to round values only for display in pandas while retaining original ones in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I wish to only round values in the DataFrame for display purposes, when I use head() or tail() but I want the DataFrame to retain the original values.

I tried using the round method but it changes the values in the original DataFrame. I don't wish to create a separate copy each time for this purpose.

Is there any other way than creating a separate copy?

I'm having trouble glancing at values because some columns have e^10 notations. I'd just like to have a look at two to three decimal places maximum and not keep glancing at exponent values.

Answer (score 37):

You can temporarily change the display option:

```
with pd.option_context('display.precision', 3):
    print(df.head())
    
       0      1      2      3      4
0 -0.462 -0.698 -2.030  0.766 -1.670
1  0.925  0.603 -1.062  1.026 -0.096
2  0.589  0.819 -1.040 -0.162  2.467
3 -1.169  0.637 -0.435  0.584  1.232
4 -0.704 -0.623  1.226  0.507  0.507
```

Or change it permanently:

```
pd.set_option('display.precision', 3)
```

A simple `print(df.head().round(3))`  would also work in this case. They will not change the DataFrame in place.

Comment: This may be obvious, but `print(df.head().round(3))` will not work if the precision option is set lower than 3. That is, `precision` overrides `round`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the precision for a specific DataFrame, you can use panda's [`Styler.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html).

To make **every column** in the DataFrame have the same precision you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.head().style.format(precision=2)

       A       B       C       D
0   0.24    1.00    0.69    0.63
1   0.99    0.22    0.09    0.34
2   0.33    0.24    0.86    0.04
3   0.65    0.13    0.54    0.18
4   0.50    0.70    0.44    0.19
```

To make **a specific column** have a different precision you can format it using a dictionary:

```
df.head().style.format({'D': '{:0.5f}'}, precision=2)

       A       B       C          D
0   0.24    1.00    0.69    0.63088
1   0.99    0.22    0.09    0.34297
2   0.33    0.24    0.86    0.03709
3   0.65    0.13    0.54    0.18494
4   0.50    0.70    0.44    0.18531
```

Answer (score 1):

`'display.precision'` will not work for `Styler` object; use `'styler.format.precision'` instead, for example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display


pd.set_option('styler.format.precision', 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(2, 3))
)
display(df.style.set_caption("Styler precision"))
```

Read my long answer on other question related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72826990/11671779).